# How to add specific missing fields to a json object by comparing with a model

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, couchdb

I'm using nodejs, couchdb for my application. In the future, if I want to check whether my documents look like the same as a model, I'm thinking to fetch all the documents and compare with the model or a schema and add the missing field to the document as null and update it. How to compare and find out the specific missing field and add it to the document(json object).

Model/Schema

```
{
  "_id": "",
  "email": "",
  "password": "",
  "mobile": "",
  "username": "",
  "sharedNetworksArr": []
}
```

After I have fetched my documents and if some of the documents look like below, I have to add the missing fields.

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "password": "abc",
  "username": "abc"
}
```

The output should be as,

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "password": "abc",
  "mobile": "",
  "username": "abc",
  "sharedNetworksArr": []
}
```

Note

> All the documents may not miss the same field and some documents might be exact as the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use ES6 spread operator like this

If you are using a single object

```
// Model/Scheme Object

const modelObject = {
    "_id": "",
    "email": "",
    "password": "",
    "mobile": "",
    "username": "",
    "sharedNetworksArr": []
};

// document returned object

const documentObject = {
    "_id": "1",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "password": "abc",
    "username": "abc"
};

/* 
    Get the result using ES6 spread operator by passing 
    the model object first, and the document object second 
*/

const outputObject = { ...modelObject, ...documentObject };

console.log(outputObject);

/* 
    { _id: '1',
    email: 'abc@gmail.com',
    password: 'abc',
    mobile: '',
    username: 'abc',
    sharedNetworksArr: []
    } 
*/
```

If you are using an array of objects. Use the Array map operator to transform the result

```
const documentObjectArray = [{
    "_id": "1",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "password": "abc",
    "username": "abc"
}, {
    "_id": "2",
    "email": "def@gmail.com",
    "password": "def",
    "username": "def"
}, {
    "_id": "3",
    "email": "ghi@gmail.com",
    "password": "ghi",
    "username": "ghi"
}];

const outputObjectArray = documentObjectArray.map((document) => {

    /*  transform result using ES6 spread operator by passing 
     the model object first, and the document object second */

    return { ...modelObject, ...document, }

});


console.log(outputObjectArray);
/*
    [ { _id: '1',
        email: 'abc@gmail.com',
        password: 'abc',
        mobile: '',
        username: 'abc',
        sharedNetworksArr: [] },
    { _id: '2',
        email: 'def@gmail.com',
        password: 'def',
        mobile: '',
        username: 'def',
        sharedNetworksArr: [] },
    { _id: '3',
        email: 'ghi@gmail.com',
        password: 'ghi',
        mobile: '',
        username: 'ghi',
        sharedNetworksArr: [] } ]
    */
```

Comment: This answer is simple, elegant and doesn't use any external lib, it should work unless you need support for nested objects.

Comment: This is simple and worked fine. Accepting your answer.

Comment: @Kola- Comparing with the model can we use this to remove a field also??

Comment: @VenuraNimesh Kindly let me know what you mean exactly. Is it remove from modelObject or from documentObject? Cheers!

Comment: @Grey Just like adding fields to the document object by comparing with the model, if there is an additional field(when comparing with the model) in the document object, is there are any ES6 operator to remove that additional field from the document object.

Comment: @VenuraNimesh just use delete. For example (using the above)... you call call "delete outputObject.mobile" (without the quote) will delete the mobile field/key from the outputObject. Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash's defaultsdeep (or just defaults) library for this.

```
const _defaultsDeep = require('lodash.defaultsdeep');
let base = {
  "_id": "",
  "email": "",
  "password": "",
  "mobile": "",
  "username": "",
  "sharedNetworksArr": []
};
let input = {
  "_id": "1",
  "email": "abc@gmail.com",
  "password": "abc",
  "username": "abc"
};
let merged = _defaultsDeep(input, base);
console.log(JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2));
```

Comment: For an array of inputs, you would use an array operation like forEach. I would also caution against using the spread operator within a map function without considering the impact. This actually constructs a new object every single time rather than modifying an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can give default value in to the model.Or you should add required field for other.

```
 { "_id": "", "email": "", "password": "", "mobile": "", "username": "", 
 "sharedNetworksArr": {default:[]} }
```